# How do you change the location of a Hyper-V VM

Tags: hyper-v

I have crated a VM in Hyper-V using the default path, which is C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V.

Is it possible to change the location of the VM without destroying it or exporting it and importing it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

http://www.virmansec.com/blogs/tjaber/archive/2010/06/07/change-the-parent-vhd-path-in-hyper-v.aspx

Comment: This article describes how to change the location of the parent VHD. I am looking to change the location of the VM config files themselves, not the VHD('s).

Comment: @Andy you should be more specific in your question.  You might want to update it.